# Why is "Merkos L'inyonei Chinuch" spelled that way?

Tags: history, hebrew, chasidut-hasidism, transliteration, chabad

In the title [Merkos L'inyonei Chinuch](http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/117670/jewish/Merkos-Linyonei-Chinuch.htm), why is the word מרכז transliterated with an 's' in place of a 'ז' rather than a 'z'?

Comment: Chabad Chasidus originates in Russia. Perhaps in Russian the Zayin translates more closely to a "s".

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because it is about how to communicate a Torah organization's name to English speakers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be under the influence of German (where *z* represents the sound /ts/, so it's unavailable for this purpose).

The first director of Merkos was [R' Chaim Mordechai Aizik Hodakov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Mordechai_Aizik_Hodakov) ע"ה, who in the '20s and '30s was the principal of the Torah Im Derech Eretz school in Riga; and one of Merkos' early influential employees was [Dr. Nissan Mindel](http://www.crownheights.info/index.php?itemid=27286) ע"ה, who had been a student at the same school. It followed the principles of R' Samson Raphael Hirsch זצ"ל (hence its name), so I would guess that they used German orthography for Hebrew transliterations.

It's also possible that this was simply the standard at the time. I don't have his sefarim handy, but I seem to remember that R' Avigdor Miller זצ"ל also occasionally used S for zayin (though he never studied in any German-influenced school).

Comment: In German, not only is the letter _z_ unavailable, but, if I'm not mistaken, a final consonant is devoiced, so that (to the extent that influenced Hebrew, as local languages always do) _merkaz_ may well have been pronounced with an _s_ sound, further encouraging such a transliteration.

Answer (score 1):

An S in English can have the sound of a [Zayin](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/esl/pronunciation/s.html) (e.g. dishes), and that was probably the intent.

Comment: Are you suggesting the transliteration was done by someone who was unaware that that pronunciation is the rare exception to the rule and therefore forewent 'z'?

Comment: Nowadays, when every second person you meet in the States is named Manmeet or Fatima, people will see an unusual word and pronounce it as if it's a transliteration; hence, they'll see _s_ and pronounce it as an _s_. However, I'm guessing (no source) that that wasn't always the case, and that someone seeing _merkos_ would pronounce it with a _z_. (Also with an _er_ as in the English word _her_, but there's not much to do about that: there's no unambiguous way to transliterate the Hebrew _er_ into English.) But that leaves open why the _o_ — and why _Machine Israel_ used to be spelled that way.

Comment: @WAF, it is hard to state a hard-and-fast rule in English pronunciation because there are always exceptions, but in general an s after a vowel is pronounced as a z, as is a final s in a word. The s is doubled to indicate that it is a proper s sound. See here: http://www.pronuncian.com/materials/podcasts/Episode_3.aspx

Comment: that is true of conventional English spelling (which actually has been [artificially conventionalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_letter_rule) to double final letters for at times unnatural reasons) but when it comes to transliteration from Hebrew, I believe the standard is to leave consonants singular unless marking a geminate for a _dagesh_. I have never, for example, seen שבת transliterated with a final 'ss'.

Comment: @WAF ssssssee here http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1266/759